# For two invariant complements in the space of representation $T$. Prove that $T_{W_1}$ isomorphic to$ T_{W_2}$

Tags: representation-theory, invariant-theory

Let $W_{1}$ and $W_{2}$ be two invariant complements of the invariant space $U$ in the space of the representation $T$ prove that $T_{W_{1}}$ equivalent to $T_{W_{2}}$.

**Invariant Complement Definition:**

[image]

**Two representations are equivalent iff:**

[image]

Could anyone give me a hint for doing so please?

Thank you

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you also give the definition for invariant complements and $T_{W_1}$.

Comment: Okay sorry I will add the definitions @Levent

Comment: I have added the definition from the book the OP is using but it is pending peer reviewing @reuns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $V=U\oplus W$. Define the quotient module $V/U$ by $g\cdot (v+U)=g\cdot v+U$ for $v\in V$ and $g\in G$. Can you show that this indeed defines a module? Then use the canonical quotient map $q:V=U\oplus W\rightarrow V/U$ and restrict it to $W$. Then $q\mid_W$ is injective since $W\cap U=\{0\}$ and surjective by the fact that $V=U+W$. Also observe that $q(g\cdot w)=g\cdot w+U =g\cdot(w+U)=g\cdot q(w)$ so $q$ is a $G$-module morphism. Hence $q$ is an isomorphism between $G$-modules. As a result any $G$-invariant complement of $U$ in $V$ is isomorphic to the module $V/U$ which implies that they are all in fact isomorphic as $G$-modules.

Edit : To clarify, I would like to explain a bit more. For a submodule $U$ of $V$, you can define the quotient module $V/U$ as a I explained above. Now, if $W$ is also a submodule of $V$ satisfying $V=U\oplus W$, the quotient map $q:V\rightarrow V/U$ will be injective when restricted to $W$ (if $q(w)=0+U$, then $w+U=0+U$ so $w\in U$, and since $U\cap W=\{0\}$ we get $w=0$. Hence $q\mid_W$ is injective). Moreover, it will be surjective since for every element $v+U$ in $V/U$ we can write $v=w+u$ for some $w\in W$ and $u\in U$ (this is true because $V=U+W$) and then $v+U=w+u+U=w+U=q(w)$. Lastly, it is a $G$-module morphism as I have shown above. Then we deduce that $q\mid_W$ is in fact an isomorphism of two $G$-modules, $W$ and $V/U$. Now this is true for every submodule $W$ of $V$ satisfying $V=U\oplus W$. Hence if both $W_1$ and $W_2$ satisfy this property, we conclude that they are both isomorphic to $V/U$ and thus, they are in fact isomorphic to each other.

Comment: Why you defined a quotient module ?

Comment: And what is the intuition behind choosing this definition specifically?

Comment: I can see that you are speaking about 2 G- modules but you defined only 1, could you please tell me what is the other G-module?

Comment: @Intuition I'd say at first $W $ (and your $W_1,W_2$) doesn't exist. You only have a representation $G,V$ and a sub-representation $G,U$. Show that $q : V \to V/U$ is well-defined and commutes with the action of $G$, obtaining a representation  $G,V/U$. Then, assume such $W$ exists (a complementary subspace which is a subrepresentation of $G,V$) and conclude

Comment: @reuns so W_1 and W_2 are the subrepresentation and the quotient representation?

Comment: @Intuition You need to make things precise. It is always the case that for some subspace $W$ we have $V = U \oplus W$. But for most such $W$ you won't have $g\cdot w \in W$ for every $w \in W,g \in G$. So in the context of $G$-modules/representations you can't identify $V/U$ with $W$ as you did in other contexts. The point of the decomposition in irreducible representations is to find if such a $W$ with $g\cdot w \in W$ exists.

Comment: I  could not understand why q restricted to W is injective and surjective could you clarify this part more than this please

Comment: @hopefully I edited.

Comment: is the module over a commutative ring?

Comment: @reuns what is the action of G here?

Comment: why did not you show that the map preserves addition ? may be you are considering it a trivial step?

Comment: @reuns why we show that q commutes with the action of G?

Comment: @Idonotknow yes, I think it is a trivial step since $q$ is the canonical quotient of vector spaces, i.e. already a linear map.

Comment: @Intuition We are trying to show that two $G$-modules are isomorphic, not two vector spaces. Hence we need to find a $G$-module morphism that has an inverse. If you want to prove that two $G$-modules are isomorphic, you cannot just write a vector space isomorphism, you also need to show that the map respects $G$-action.